# A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_database'.(Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

I have this error would someone you tell me what's the solution for it. It displays Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-6.0.0\android\build.gradle' from cache. I'm not sure what is causing the error because all my dependencies are among the latest versions.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_database'.
> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_database-6.0.0\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_database' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [project ':firebase_core'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

These are my dependencies from the pubspec.yaml file in my project.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.8 
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.1
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
  geolocator: ^6.1.1
  http: 
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

in the project level build.gradle add:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
```

and in the app level build.gradle add :

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//above the dependencies tag
```

Comment: Already have those added to my build.gradles  but still displaying the same error